# SQL Server Equivalent of Oracle dbms_job.submit

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, oracle10g

Hope someone can help me.  I've been asked to convert an Oracle database to SQL Server 2012, I've got most of the stored procs done but I'm stuck on one.  Does anyone have any idea what the SQL Server equivalent of the follow proc would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "BACKUPJOB" AS
JobNo user_jobs.job%TYPE;
BEGIN
   dbms_job.submit(JobNo,
              'begin  PR_GET_OLD_HISTORY(NULL); end;',
               SYSDATE,
              'SYSDATE + 30');
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below stored procedure in online to create jobs via T-SQL

sp_add_job - adds a new job executed by the SQLServerAgent service.

sp_add_jobstep - Adds a step (operation) to a job.

sp_add_jobstep - Creates a schedule for a job. sp_add_jobschedule is provided for backward compatibility only.

sp_add_jobserver - Targets the specified job at the specified server.

all these stored procedures are in MSDB Database.

Ex:

```
USE msdb ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'NightlyBackups';
GO
```